# Tracking all events on a website

Tags: web, analytics, tracking

I'm looking to track all events on my website and store them in a database.
Specifically, I want to track

1. Mouse movements
2. Clicks
3. Forms
4. Pages

Are there any existing frameworks in place for doing this similar to what sites like Hotjar and Mixpanel does? Or would I need to attach some eventListeners myself?

Answer (score 0):

To some degree, you can track these actions relatively easily with simple `GTM` implementations with event tracking.

Many databases have a native connector to Google Analytics via GA's API. You can then download the data from GA into your database, or use third-party tools like Supermetric or Alteryx to populate the GA data into your database.

1. Mouse movement. This can get ugly very quickly with the potential amount of data collected. From my experience, UX analysis tools such as HotJar as you mentioned or Crazy Egg would probably be better suited for such data unless you have a very predefined and specific use case.
2. Quite easy to track as Events in GA.
3. Relatively easy to track as Events in GA.
4. Pages. GA is really good at this and the default set up works for most simple scenarios.
5. Potential you might want to track scroll depth and time-on-element tracking, etc. There are plugins that let you do that easily with GA as well.

There are lots of resources and tutorials online. Do a quick search in Google and let me know if you have any other specific questions.